# Are kerberos tickets modifiable as part of an HTTP request payload?

Tags: kerberos

At what network layer are kerberos tickets present during communication between a browser and web-server?

Are they modifiable as part of the HTTP payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a basic misunderstanding of kerberos tickets. They cannot be modified at any point. They are encrypted in the server's key, any changes you make will invalidate the ticket.

If you are asking when to present the ticket as part of the http exchange, then you need to specify which server and exact protocol you are using. The most common use of kerberos with http is via SPNEGO.

This is documented in in rfc4559

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4559